# How to create .txt file in Temporary Internet folder?

Tags: c++

I want to create a .txt file inside Temporary Internet folder.For that I am reading registry.I am reading `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User` Shell Folders\Cache. But this give me path `**%USERPROFILE%\Local Settings\Temporary Internet Files**.`
Here I need a absolute path like `C:\Documents and Settings\UserName\Local Settings\Temporary Internet Files`, so that I can create my .txt file ?
Can anybody tell me how to do that ?
Please Help me.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ExpandEnvironmentString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724265(VS.85).aspx)

Comment: @peterchen: Iam now able to create file, but when I am searching that directory I am not able to locate it.
Can u tell where I may be wrong...

Comment: what do you mean by "searching"? 1. With windows explorer? 2. Are you trying to open it using OpenFile? 3. Are you trying FindFirst/NextFile?  With what options?

Comment: Please shwo the code of the call that fails, and the error code you get.

Comment: Sorry for not giving detail, I am just opening that folder & trying to locate that file, but I am not able to...